# CakePHP: Apply bootstrap.css only to content of certain views, not layout

Tags: php, css, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a site with a designer, and he already coded the entire static webpage with HTML/CSS.

We needed an admin backend and an Auth component, so I figured a simple CakePHP app would work well, instead of hacking together a custom PHP/MySQL solution.
I converted all of his static pages to CakePHP syntax, creating simple views using the PagesController. I created a completely separate layout for the admin backend using Bootstrap 3.0.

On a few of the frontend pages, like our "Sign Up" and "Login Page", I want to utilize Bootstrap 3.0's nice CSS and Javascript components (especially its clean form styles).

However, when I include Bootstrap in the `<head>` of the layout, it conflicts with the CSS classes that the designer created, totally messing up the layout of the page.

I basically was wondering if there was a way I could apply a CSS stylesheet *ONLY* to the content of a view (i.e. signup.ctp), and not its layout (default.ctp)? This would save me a lot of time and headaches.

Answer (score 1):

In your view file i.e. `signup.ctp` just include the css using Html helper as like this

```
echo $this->Html->css('your_css_file', null, array(
    'inline' => false
));
```

and make sure you've the line `$this->fetch('css')` in your layout file. so it'll include the above css in the section where you've defined `$this->fetch('css')`.

For example:

```
<head>
    <?php $this->fetch('css') ?>
</head>
```

Will include the css in `head` section which you've defined in view

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is enclose your content in a div with a specific id like `<div id="bootstrap"></div>`, and then prepend all your css selectors in bootstrap with #bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Include the Bootstrap 3 css in the required view files only using HTML helper:

**$this->Html->css();**

Document page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css